# External nameserver trouble for kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes

My pods can not resolve external world ( for ex for mail, ... ) how can I add google nameserver to the cluster ? For info the host resolve it without problem and has nameserver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the liveness check made skids fail, I changed it like bellow.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: kube-dns-v10
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v10
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
        version: v10
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: etcd
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        command:
        - /usr/local/bin/etcd
        - -data-dir
        - /var/etcd/data
        - -listen-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -advertise-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -initial-cluster-token
        - skydns-etcd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: etcd-storage
          mountPath: /var/etcd/data
      - name: kube2sky
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.12
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/kube2sky"
        - --domain=cluster.local
      - name: skydns
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/skydns"
        - -machines=http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -addr=0.0.0.0:53
        - -ns-rotate=false
        - -domain=cluster.local.
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 15
        #readinessProbe:
          #httpGet:
            #path: /healthz
            #port: 8080
            #scheme: HTTP
          #initialDelaySeconds: 1
          #timeoutSeconds: 5
      - name: healthz
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz:1.0
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        args:
        - -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null
        - -port=8080
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: etcd-storage
        emptyDir: {}
      dnsPolicy: Default  # Don't use cluster DNS.
```